# Installing Railo 4 and Resin 4 on IIS 8 (Server 2012)

Tags: railo, iis-8, resin

I am trying to get Railo working in IIS 8 on Server 2012. I'm using Resin as my Java application server.

I've followed the instructions here:

http://www.getrailo.org/index.cfm/documentation/installation/railo-resin-apache/

What I've done so far is the bit that configures Resin to use Railo for .cf* files. Unfortunately, while Resin does work on the default port 8080, .cfm files are NOT being rendered through Railo. They just show up as plaintext.

I've tried pointing railo-web-directory and railo-server-directory to explicit locations in Resin's app-default.xml, but that hasn't worked.

I haven't even tried getting Resin and IIS playing nicely yet. I want to make sure Resin can render CFML correctly before I embark on that challenge.

Comment: Do you have a specific reason for using Resin? The Railo Installer will setup Railo on Tomcat and connect it to IIS.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of Tomcat, and previously used Resin without any problems on a Server 2008 R2 box. I'd rather find out why Resin isn't working, tbh.

Comment: Well if it's just not liking Tomcat, you can also grab the Jetty version (Railo Express) which comes pre-configured to serve CFML files. There's also [Helicon Zoo](http://www.helicontech.com/articles/category/helicon-zoo/) which makes it easy to setup Railo+Jetty on IIS.

Comment: If you _really_ want to go with Resin, you might want to check if there's a mailing list for it, since the Resin tag here [doesn't have many followers](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/resin/topusers).

Comment: I might try Express. I originally tried Helicon Zoo, and it didn't work at all, so I figured I'd try to get things set up myself.